# diff: delete one line and then add another - what line number is meant in the add command?

Tags: diff

There are two files, `a` and `b`, with such contents:

**a**

```
apples
oranges
kiwis
carrots
```

**b**

```
apples
kiwis
carrots
grapefruits
```

Next, I do `diff` for them:

```
$ diff a b
2d1
< oranges
4a4
> grapefruits
```

After `2d1` `a` should contain

```
apples
kiwis
carrots
```

But how then can `4a4` be applied afterwards? According to `info diff`

> ‘*l*a*r*’: Add the lines in range *r* of the second file **after** line *l* of the
> first file.

To my knowledge, it means here "copy the line 4 (`grapefruits`) from `b` to the line 5 of `a`", what is of course wrong. I would rather say that we need `3a4` here as it will place `grapefruits` just **after** the third line (`carrots`) in `a`.

So how can I relate such output to what is stated in `info diff`?

Comment: The Starting number refers to original unchanging line number in "a" , then the Character is the Operation ( Delete , Append , Change ) , then the last number is the "modified" line number in "b" , corresponding to applying all Operations till that Point.

Comment: Hence , `2d1` means go to line 2 in "a" , then Delete , you will land in line 1 in "b" , `4a4` means go to line 4 in "a" (unchanged) , then Append , you will land in line 4 in "b".

Comment: This formatting has the advantage that when you just pick the first number for a Particular Diff & navigate to that line in `vi` , you will land up at the correct line.

Comment: @Prem I get the picture, thank you. But can you clarify a little what does "modified" mean in your words *the last number is the "modified" line number in "b"*? Why is the second number modified?

Comment: It means that the last line number is valid only when we have applied all the Diffs till that Point. Eg , When we have 6 Diffs between "a" & "b" , then the Starting number is always valid in "a" , we can always go to that line number in "a". In "b" , when considering Diff 5 , we must apply Diff 1 to Diff 4 , only then the last number will be valid in "b". We are modifying "b" by applying each Diff , hence we get the modified line number. Maybe , by tomorrow , I will try to put in a longer Example to show this.